# Zend Controller Action , get Helper in other class?

Tags: php, zend-framework

is there any way to get an Action Helper from an Service Class?

I have the following Helper:

```
class Helper_Host extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Return Hosturl with path
     *
     * @return string Hostname
     */
    public function direct()
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $host = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $host .= $front->getBaseUrl() . '/';
        return (string) $host;
    }
}
```

Now i want to get the Hostname from "My_Service_XYZ" , getStaticHelper is not working like excepted (;

```
class My_Service_XYZ {

    public function test()
    {
        $h = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Host');
        return $h->host(); // not working..
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    class My_Service_XYZ {

        public function test()
        {
            $h = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Host');
            return $h->direct(); // not working..
        }

    }
```

should works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
$h = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('Host');
```

instead of:

```
$h = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('FlashMessenger');
```