# Accessing action helpers from my models in zend

Tags: zend-framework

Can I access my action helpers from my models?
What am avoiding is creating new models and calling the functions everytime I need some functionality.

Any tips?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What about:

```php
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('helpername')->doStuff();
```

Comment: Do I call the helper $this->_helper->getuseremail(); in my controllers.How will this example apply in my models?

Comment: Thanks.It lead me to the correct solution and posted the link

Answer (score 1):

if helper not registered you can get as
$helper = new Library_Helper_Helper();

Answer (score 0):

After a few searches [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926710/zend-controller-action-get-helper-in-other-class/1942243#1942243) lead me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nice call @Daniel V - you can obviously bootsrap them for use in controllers, but models need to be directly instantiated